# GPS tracking app in Xamarin stop working in the background after a while

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gps, tracking

I'm trying to make a gps tracking app in `Xamarin` that works in the background too. Currently I have created a service that every two seconds checks the location of the device.

I am currently testing it on an **Android Honor 10** and I notice that when i launch the app in debug with **Visual Studio** keeping the phone connected to the PC it works without ever stopping.

If, on the other hand, I try the app without debugging, after a while it stop tracking gps if I put it in the background.

So this is my **service** in the **main project**:

```
public class TrackingService
{
    readonly bool stopping = false;
    public TrackingService()
    {
    }

    public async Task Run(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => {
            while (!stopping)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(2000);

                    var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best);
                    var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
                    //Other stuff like writing coordinates into a local database
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        //Error
                    });
                }
            }
            return;
        }, token);
    }
}
```

This is the the start of the service for the **Android project**:

```
[Register("com.companyname.dolomicchiostreetapp.TrackingService")]
public class AndroidLocationService : Service
{
    CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    public const int SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 10000;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Notification notif = DependencyService.Get<INotification>().ReturnNotif();
        StartForeground(SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);

        Task.Run(() => {
            try
            {
                var locShared = new TrackingService();
                locShared.Run(_cts.Token).Wait();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var message = new StopServiceMessage();
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                        () => MessagingCenter.Send(message, "ServiceStopped")
                    );
                }
            }
        }, _cts.Token);

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (_cts != null)
        {
            _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            _cts.Cancel();
        }
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```

And this is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.dolomicchiostreetapp">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="dolomicchiostreetapp.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
      <service android:enabled="true" android:foregroundServiceType="location" android:exported="false" android:name="com.companyname.dolomicchiostreetapp.TrackingService" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
</manifest>
```

I followed this github example: [XamarinForms.LocationService](https://github.com/shernandezp/XamarinForms.LocationService)

Has anyone ever had this problem ?

Thanks to those who will help me.

Answer (score 1):

See [Limited Updates to Background Tracking](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background#limit-updates) - "Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher - Android preserves device battery life by ... If your app is running in the background, it can receive **location updates only a few times each hour**".

If you want more frequent updates, then you need a [`Foreground Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)).

Comment: I have implemented as in this example: https://github.com/shernandezp/XamarinForms.LocationService/blob/master/XamarinForms.LocationService.Android/MainActivity.cs

In fact, when I start the service I have the icon in the status bar that remains active for me as a notification

Comment: Ok. I had missed the `StartForeground` in your code. Between that and the status icon, (and of course the permission, I see you have that), you've done as much as I know to do.